# Android studio language query

Tags: java, android

Not showing language option (java,kotlin) while creating new project.

I am expecting to write code in java but it's creating .kt file.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Java file.  Projects don't have to be one or the other, the two languages can call each other.  You can have some files in Java and some in kotlin if you want